# 'this.$refs' is always empty in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ref

I'm trying to do a standard implementation of `ref` so that I can insert children elements into my `InfoBox`. But whatever I seem to put as a 'ref' element, never makes it to my InfoBox component. The result is always `{} undefined` from the log calls.

The click handler is to test timing issues, as using `created` vs `mounted` seemed to be a common issue.

```
<InfoBox
  v-if="waitingForCode">
  <p ref="infoboxcontent">A 7-digit verification code has been sent.</p>
</InfoBox>
```

and

```
<template>
  <div
    class="info-box"
    @click="clicked" >
    {{ this.$refs.infoboxcontent }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'InfoBox',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs, this.$refs.infoboxcontent)
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      console.log(this.$refs, this.$refs.infoboxcontent)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  // some style
</style>
```

I'm starting to think I fundamentally misunderstand the usage of the 'ref' attribute since this seems like a trivial example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If think you're using refs where you should be using slots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) Vue special attribute is used to refer a DOM node (or a child component) from your *current component template*.

If you want to pass some content to a custom component, this is the use case for a [`<slot>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot-1) Vue built-in component.

Comment: also: An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render. [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)